# Sequential container adaptors in C++

Tags: c++, sequential

What is the purpose of the sequential container adaptors (i.e; stack, queue) in C++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

They provide a narrower interface that enforces additional [invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29), and are therefore safer to use when you want those invariants to be kept.

Comment: can you just explain this more further in a simple way? Thanks.

Comment: Consider a function, *f*, in your program where you have access to an object, *x*, which *f* will manipulate. When you write *f* you will have to make some assumptions about the state of *x* (the kinds of values its data members may hold): these are the *preconditions* of *f*. If those assumptions are wrong the program will misbehave (it will have a bug). The *invariants* of *x* are assumptions that it is very safe for you to make about the state of *x* when you are writing *f*.

Answer (score 1):

1. they keep you from doing things that you decided to be unlegal (eg. if the order of processing elements is important you can use a stack for the proper order)
2. they point out the proper usage of a container to the user of your code (eg. prevent the user from accessing data he shouldn't be)
3. they allow to implement the same structure using different underlying types (eg. depending on your exact problem you may be better off implementing a stack on top of a [deque](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html) or on top of a [vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html))

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to your question would be to read the following book:

[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)

However if you want a quick and dirty answer:  Not only do stacks and queues model real world objects such as program stacks and process queues, they also are optimal for random insert and delete operations.